# Calculate the display width of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

A Java version of this question was just answered, and, well, I don't know how to do this in .net.

So how do you calculate the display width of a string in C# / .net?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You've got the same problem in this question as was present in the Java question - not enough information! It will differ between WinForms and WPF.

For WinForms: [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

For WPF I'm not sure, but I suspect it will depend on the exact way you're drawing the text...

Comment: In WPF you would use FormattedText, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx.

Comment: How would you do that in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Shimmy: Well in ASP.NET it will entirely depend on what the browser does. It's really not the sort of thing you'd try to do in a web app - you'd use CSS to control the formatting instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't have to be accurate, I just need to create a function that makes up a summary of a long file name so truncating it and leaving the extension i.e. msdfjkasdfjhkjhadf...pdf

Comment: @Shimmy: It's not a matter of accuracy - it's a matter of it being basically impossible to predict from the server side. You'd need to do it on the client side if anywhere. But anyway, it's definitely not a .NET question. I suggest you ask a new question, giving your requirements very precisely.

Comment: @JonSkeet Having problem with Graphics.MeasureString. Using monospaced font Courier New and still i get different values for different characters. Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362999/strange-behavior-while-computing-string-width-in-pixels-for-simulation-of-word-w

Answer (score 67):

An alternative for Windows Forms is the static TextRenderer.MeasureText method.

Although restricted to integer sizes, this (in tandem with TextRenderer.DrawText) renders more accurate and much higher quality ClearType text than the Graphics.MeasureString/DrawString duo.

Comment: Cool. Never heard of the TextRenderer before.

Comment: For reference: [TextRenderer.MeasureText on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx)

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704923/textrenderer-measuretext-and-graphics-measurestring-mismatch-in-size
and this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/10/13/480632.aspx
for more information. It would seem that use of TextRenderer.MeasureText is the method applicable to most usage of .Net WinForms.

Answer (score 24):

In WPF you would use [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx).

Comment: text in upper case not measured properly .

Answer (score 9):

`Graphics.MeasureString` but its a bit crappy, as is explained and improved upon; [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/measurestring.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You would use Graphics.MeasureString.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

Comment: WinForms controls expose a `CreateGraphics` method that can be used to create the `Graphics` object in the first place (its constructor is private)

Answer (score 1):

Graphics.MeasureString([text to measure],[font being used to measure text]);

The resulting object will provide the following:

[image: properties available]

Other overloads of MeasureString also available.