# In wpf how to calculate pixel length of string?

Tags: wpf

I have a string to draw in a custom dialog box. How can i get the required length of string in pixels using WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the display width of a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Please be aware that most calculations in the answers that will be given will not be in pixels but in 1/96 of an inch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show it afterwards within a TextBlock, create the TextBlock and call [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx). Make sure that the TextBlock has set the right font size before calling Measure.

Another way is to go via [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx), if you want to do your calculations on a low level.

Comment: +1.  FormattedText is real nice and even handles the same options as TextBlock such as abbreviating with ... when the string is too long.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need the (pixel) size.

It might be better to automatically size the dialog to its content.