# Retrieving width of result of Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a code where I draw a string to screen. Let's say I need to draw two words next to each other, each word may have different font. How do I retrive the width of printed text so that I can adjust the axis to start drawing the second word next to first one?

Comment: _t.DrawString(part.text, this.Font, _b, X, Y);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: yes it is, I think if this answer was more descriptive it would be more helpful for other people, right now it doesn't say much apart of that link :), but linked document contains it

Comment: From the link: "To obtain metrics suitable for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method".

Answer (score 3):

You want [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx).

Comment: wish I could check both answers