# Finding out whether string can fit into rectangle on the screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, user-interface

Given a string with known formatting options, and a rectangle of known dimensions in pixels (widht, height), what is the best way to determine whether the string can fit for display in the given rectangle screen size of the current screen?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You'll need to either have a graphics object or create one, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c), for example.

MeasureString returns a `Sizef`, which you can easily compare to your rectangle, [which also has a Size property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Edit:** For WPF, you can also look into this: [WPF equivalent to TextRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824281/wpf-equivalent-to-textrenderer)