# Specify max width for a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, format

So I have to manage a listbox that has columns like table and I would like to give each column a fixed width.
I wrote this method to convert the strings into a fixed length:

```
const int nameMaxWidth = 20;
int nameLength = name.Length;

if (nameLength < 20)
{
   while (nameLength < 20)
   {
      name = name + " ";
      nameLength++;
   }
}
else
{
   name = name.Substring(0, nameMaxWidth);
}
```

but it seems that it does not work since each letter has different size, for example nnnnn is longer than iiiii although both have the same length. I have tried String.Format but it doesnt work either. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @JamieRees its WindowsForms

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+measure+string+width+in+pixels (and [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c) covers some way). If you think that answer does not cover your scenario - make sure to clarify what did not work and specify framework you are using (as solutions are different, especially between desktop and web variations).

Comment: @BlameTheBrian this question has been answered.

Comment: The "width" of a `string` depends on the font it's displayed in (and the font size of course). If you know all that, you can try using [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

Comment: my bad, I haven't searched with that keywords as I am new to C#. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried all the methods I could find on the interwebnets, but I have not found any way to get a consistently accurate measurement of a string. I ended up padding the strings with a space at either end to allow for inaccuracies.

Comment: @Ulric yeah I don't know why Microsoft does not create an equivalent method to string format in java. The methods used in above answer seems too complicated for a newbie like me :D