# Resize width on Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#

I'm somewhat new to coding and I'm making an application in Windows Forms C#.

What I want to do is resize some of the forms depending on the length of a string. It's doing a calculation with some inputs, and if the output can't all be seen in the form I want it to be resized.

I have done this so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public Form3(int age, string name)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Variables.age = age;
            Variables.name = name;

            if (Variables.length > 22)
            {
                this.Width = Variables.length * 5;
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the display width of a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Why is the `InitializeComponent();` commented? What is `Variable` ?

Comment: @Sinatr WHAT? This has is similar like *java* and *javascript* or *car* and *carpet*

Comment: @Thomas Oh well, I just commented it out for the show in this post. It's not like this in my actual code.

Comment: Then show us actual code, it will be simpler for us to help you

Comment: @Sinatr I don't think that it is a duplicate but the topic you comment can be the answer for StevoHN

StevoHN you can maybe try with:

    this.Width = Graphics.MeasureString(name);

Comment: You don't show us the class definition of the `Variables` object, so we can't tell how its `length` property is initialized. If it's not being initialized, then we must assume a default value of zero... which means your `if` statement is never triggered.

And while your resizing technique will crudely do what you describe, there are ways to make it much more precise (as @Fleve mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole point that the [AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property was created. It will enable dynamic growing and shrinking based on your form's content. Also, it has several different modes.