# What are available monospaced fonts in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, label, fixed-width

According to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font
I tried to use Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, Monaco, and Consolas. 
Why I　find only "Courier New" and "Consolas" are actually monospaced and hence support fixed width of letters so I can align my multiple lines of text well?
My text looks like this:
    ABC    111
   ABXa    22222222
 Haaaih    3333
    uiu    asx

Where I can find a full list of fonts which support fixed width letters in C#?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think its specific to C#. Any system installed monospaced font will do.

Comment: But why use Lucida Console as the font of my text label in C#, it doesn't display letters in a fixed width way?

Comment: I agree that monospaced fonts is not specific to C#. But my question is why some monospaced fonts like Lucida Console doesn't display fixed width for each letter in C#?

Comment: Sorry, not aware that we cannot ask for the reference materials in this site. I use the Consolas anyway and it supports the fixed width. You can help close the question. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack you may want to consider would be to [query the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263614/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-c) of various characters using the given font. For example, if 'W', 'i', 'O', and 'l' are all the same width, then you are probably dealing with a fixed width font.

Comment: So do we have any documents telling us the whole list of all available monospaced fonts in C#? Or any documents/code explaining why Monaco, or Lucida Console etc. doesn't display with fixed width letters in C#?